# Restoring Deleted Bootcamp Partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility

I damaged a bootcamp install on container 'disk1' by deleting the windows partition there from disk utility. Anyway to get that back? I really just want 1 or 2 files on from that partition.

Perhaps windows might help so I want to try to install a second windows bootcamp to access and/or repair 'disk1' but I don't want Bootcamp Assistant to touch 'disk1'. I want it to create a new container 'disk2'  to try to get at fix the files in windows 'disk1' partition.

My options:

1. force bootcamp assistant to create 'disk2' install bootcamp
2. rename 'disk1' to 'disk2', install bootcamp
3. repair damaged 'disk1' from macOS somehow or use parallels

Its a MacBook Pro with an SSD so I think **Trim** has erased the data. I just want to try something. Acronis perhaps from another windows install?

Container with deleted partition I am trying to recover.
[image: Disk Utility]

Trying to install another bootcamp to repair disk1 but I want it to use a different container like disk2 so it doesn't touch disk1.
[image]

Comment: 1) Don't attempt to install [or even write] anything at all when you have a deleted partition, most especially on an SSD - the drive will be quite happy to write all over it. 2) Boot Camp will not make two installs.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my assessment of what you did. If I am wrong, post a comment.

Your version of macOS is either Big Sur or Monterey. Your internal SSD initially three partitions. Initially, the NTFS formatted Windows volume resided in the third partition (`disk0s3`). You used the Disk Utility to replace this partition with a new partition which was initialized as an APFS container (`disk1`). You then removed all volumes in this container, which by default would be a single volume (`disk1s1`).

The equation below indicates there is no appreciable free space below this new partition.

```
257 GB + 42 GB ≃ 299.8 GB
```

The values of 257 GB and 42 GB where taken from the second image you posted and the value of 299.8 GB was taken from the first image you posted. This means the new partition spans most (if no all) of the original Windows partition.

I should point out that the macOS you have currently installed can read NTFS formatted volumes. Installing Windows will probably not cause the missing NTFS formatted volume to become accessible. At least not under the circumstances which you lost the volume.

The actions you have executed so far should have caused the header of the NTFS volume to be overwritten. If so, then you will not be able to recover files my just mounting the volume.

There are a variety of third party applications which can be used to recover lost files. These exist for both macOS and Windows. Such applications may require removal of third partition from the partition table in order to search for files residing in the space occupied by this partition.

If you still want to install Windows, then consider installing Windows on an external drive. Or, shrink container where macOS resides, then install Windows in the free space. Both of these installs will have to be done manually without the use of the Boot Camp Assistant.